# Google Analytics G4 Real Time Trend Lag

Tags: google-analytics

Now that Google Analytics UA is almost dead (my main site stopped tracking today), I was wondering if it was possible to bring some of the important UA features to G4 by the way of configuration changes.

Unlike UA, there seems to be a lag in real time data and trend lines lag by about 8 hours which makes them quite useless.

Is there anyway to overcome G4 lag issues?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting more real-time data, you can link your GA4 property to a BigQuery project. Within a GA4 BigQuery project, there is an `intraday` table that will give you real-time data for the past 24hrs or so.

You can hook into this data set anyway you like (I prefer Looker) and have more real-time access. Outside of this feature, I am not aware of any other way to get more real-time data.

If you chose to go this route, be advised that BigQuery has limitation on their free tier. You might bump against it depending on what you are doing.